# Elixir Phoenix global variable plug

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to get the identifier of a website based on its domain, but after writing a plug for it, i am running into a problem wherein all the links in the system are returning the root url content.

lib/myapp/plugs/request_var.ex

```
defmodule Myapp.Plug.RequestVar do
  import Plug.Conn

  @doc false
  def init(default), do: default

  @doc false
  def call(conn, router) do
    host = conn.host
    if host == "ll.com" || host == "domain1.com" do
      slug = "domain1"
    else
      slug = "domain2"
    end

    conn |> put_private(:site_slug, slug)
  end
end
```

In lib/myapp/endpoint.ex

```
plug Myapp.Plug.RequestVar, Myapp.Router
plug Myapp.Router
```

Is anything wrong with this plug?

**Edit:** Fixed the "if" condition based on the responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `url` is generated from your `endpoint.url` and not the `host` for the `Plug.Conn`

From https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/8fe0538fd7be2adb05e2362b02fa8bd6bf3c6c46/lib/phoenix/router/helpers.ex#L13:

```
  def url(_router, %Conn{private: private}) do
    private.phoenix_endpoint.url
  end

  def url(_router, %Socket{endpoint: endpoint}) do
    endpoint.url
  end

  def url(_router, %URI{} = uri) do
    uri_to_string(uri)
  end

  def url(_router, endpoint) when is_atom(endpoint) do
    endpoint.url
  end
```

You can override this by using [struct_url/0](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.0.3/lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex#L366):

```
struct_url = update_in(Endpoint.struct_url.host, fn (_) -> "domain2" end)
some_url(struct_url, :index)
```

You can also define a second endpoint for your second domain. If your links are internal then you should consider using the `_path` functions instead of the `_url` functions. The `_url` helpers are generally used when the domain is required (such as emails.)

Comment: Thanks Gazler. Can you also tell where i should place this code of struct_url overriding so that its globally effective? Sorry, i am very new to Phoenix.

Comment: @PratikKhadloya First of all, do you definitely need to use the `_url` format and not the `_path` format? If you do then can you tell me where you are calling this from?

Comment: One of my links is a login link, which i am not sure how to use _url. `<%= link "Login", to: "/login", class: "nav-link" %>`. When i click on this link it returns the entire html of the home page again, giving a feeling that nothing is happening in the page. I haven't tried the struct_url solution yet.

Comment: @PratikKhadloya Isn't your log in link intended to link relative to the current url? For example using `login_path(@conn, :index)` would link to `/login` and `login_url(@conn, :index)` would link to `http://example.com/login`

Comment: Thanks @Gazler setting the struct_url with _url path did make it work to link it to http://ll.com:4000/register, but it still loads the home page and not the registration page :(

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your `if` clause. It will always be `true`.

```
iex(1)> host = "l2.com"
"l2.com"
iex(2)> host == "ll.com" || "domain1.com"
"domain1.com"
```

For both valid and invalid domains.

```
iex(3)> host = "ll.com"                  
"ll.com"
iex(4)> host == "ll.com" || "domain1.com"
true
```

Test:

```
iex(6)> if host == "ll.com" || "domain1.com" do
...(6)>   IO.puts "if"
...(6)> end
if
:ok
```

You have to change your clause to `if host == "ll.com" || host == "domain1.com" do`. But. It is not idiomatic to use this kind of clauses. It is generally better to use [pattern-matching](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html).

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the if condition, but that did not solve the problem :(.